# Yojson to parse int64 (ocaml)

Tags: json, ocaml, bigint, int64

As of my understanding this {"xxx": 1000000000000000} is valid right?

Not sure how to parse it with Yojson.Safe. I'm looking for something like _ `Int64 of int64 _ , but none provided, there are only _ `Int of int _ and _ `Intlit of string _ on the api.

Edit, this is my problem

```
let x = "{\"xxx\": 10000000000000}"
let json = Yojson.Safe.from_string x
match json with `Assoc [("xxx", `Intlit yyy)] -> yyy | _ -> assert false
```

It won't match because the type of json is

```
val json : Yojson.Safe.json = `Assoc [("xxx", `Int 10000000000000)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Yojson returns `Int` if it fits in an OCaml `int` and `` `Intlit `` otherwise so you need to treat all the cases:

```
match json with 
| `Assoc [("xxx", `Intlit lit)] -> Int64.of_string lit
| `Assoc [("xxx", `Int i)] -> Int64.of_int i
```

Comment: Ok, completely changed my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see, Yojson.Safe will convert that to `Intlit if the number is bigger than `Int. That's what I missed.